# Do I have to keep changing sectors or can I load multiple

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

So I finally found an example on how to leave the first sector so I can continue to load code.

- Do I have to keep changing sectors every time I use 512 bytes?
- Can I load multiple sectors at once, aka all of them? and if so is there a 
  limit to how many sectors I can load at once?

I'm calling this to load the next sector

```
load_sector1:
xor ah, ah
int 0x13
clc
mov bx, 0x07E0
mov es, bx
xor bx, bx
mov ah, 0x02
mov al, 0x1
mov ch, 0x0
mov cl, 0x2 ; Sector
mov dh, 0x0
int 0x13
jmp 0x0:0x7E00
```

If I can load multiple sectors, would I just repeat my code but change the sector number or would I have to do something entirely different?

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: "Can I load multiple sectors at once" Have you even read the docs for [int 0x13 ah=02](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/13/6.html)?  Or did you just make up that value for `al`? "Do I have to keep changing sectors every time I use 512 bytes?" I don't even know what this means.  If you keep reading the same sector from the disk, you are going to keep getting the same data.  If you want different data, read a different sector. Since you (apparently) already know that `cl` contains the sector number, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : I think what he is asking is if he needs to read each sector one at a time or can he read more than one at a time. The general rule of thumb I believe use to be that you shouldn't read a number of sectors that crosses beyond a cylinder(track) boundary as it wasn't always supported by all BIOSes.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Which is why I asked where he got the his value for `al`? Since every int 13 reference I've seen describes `al` as "number of sectors to read", the question seems to answer itself. As for the more reasonable question of "What's the max number of sectors I can read?", the fact that you must also supply the cylinder and head implies the maximum ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector#Sectors)): 63. The ability to "multitrack" into the next C&H is unexpected, but mentioned in the link I gave him. The question of "Do I have to keep changing sectors" is just weird.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : For more universal bootloaders you don't really want to read a number of sectors that crosses a cylinder boundary. There is the sector you want to start reading from and there is the number of sectors to read.These days you'll likely not have issues but if you run on older hardware- 255 is the maximum sectors to read (it isn't confined to the sector number you start at) but may not necessarily be supported depending on the CHS you start at and the the antiquity of the BIOS. If you start reading@the last sector on a track then reading 2 sectors could be an issue for some BIOSes

Comment: Generally I'd compute the distance between the CHS that I want to start at and the last CHS on the same cylinder as I started on. I'd read that many number of tracks only. That keeps almost all the BIOSes happy. The easiest way to avoid that issue is to read a sector at a time in a loop, the downside being that on real floppy drives that can have a noticeable speed impact.

Comment: I said 256 is the max above. I meant 255.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - While that may all be true, I think that's (much) more advanced than OP was looking for.  Given that he just figured out how to read sector #2 and is puzzling about how to read #3, jumping straight to multitrack seems a bit of a leap.  Encouraging him to read some of the standard references about the BIOS interrupts he is using, to think about the implications of the parameters he is passing seemed a better approach. Still, now that he's got both, hopefully he'll understand how to proceed.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : Maybe the complexity of the problem didn't go unnoticed by the OP and thus the reason why he asked the question. The answer isn't as simple as it may seem if you are targeting a variety of hardware. Simple question with an answer and many caveats. Personally I thought this was a good question as it has been a point of concern for bootloader developers for decades.

Comment: You need also to advance data buffer pointer between calls to not overwrite the same memory with new sector data, but that's sort of "obvious", right? And with long files (64+kiB) I would rather start at some `es:0000` target area, and advance the `es` only, seems simpler to me. And make sure you have enough free memory area there. As you marked this as "bootloader", if your "kernel" has 350+kiB (like 2MiB file), you may need first/between to switch to protected mode to arrange memory to have more than ~400kiB of free RAM for reading (but then you need a way to call BIOS from PM).

Comment: Thank you for the comments and you answered my question. I currently don't have a "kernel". Over the summer I decided to try and write a bootloader and a kernel and I just couldn't and still can't understand how a kernel is loaded into memory ( if it's loaded into memory at all I'm very new too this please don't kill me). So I've finally figured out how to load sectors and from there I've just put my "kernel" into the same file as my bootloader when coding it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Can you post the "multiple as long as you don't cross a cylinder boundary" as the safe portable answer?  Or is this a duplicate.