# How i can load more code to memory from a second-stage bootloader?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, bios

i load my second sector( a bootloader expansion ), with that code:

```
mov ah, 00;                     // reset disk
int 13h;                        // disk interrupt

mov ax, 0x0000;                 // register ax [0000]:1000
mov bx, 0x1000;                 // register bx  0000:[1000]

mov ah, 0x2;                    // read sector instruction
mov al, 0x2;                    // sectors to read
mov ch, 0x0;                    // cylinder
mov cl, 0x6;                    // local to write
mov dh, 0x0;                    // head

int 0x13;                       // call the disk interupter

jmp 0x0000:0x1000;              // Jump to kernel
```

but i want to load another kernel at memory( the protected mode kernel ), how i can use this code to load it or i got to use other way?

bootloader = 1 sector 512 bytes

kernel x16 = 2 sector 1024 bytes

kernel x32 = 2 sector 1024 bytes ( i know that i can load more, changing AL )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to load the 32-bit kernel over your 16-bit kernel while it's running so you need to use a different memory address for the data to be loaded.  (In the disk-read call and the far jmp).

But yes, obviously the same BIOS call works the same way while you're still in 16-bit real mode.  @MichaelPetch commented on [Do I have to keep changing sectors or can I load multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373623/do-i-have-to-keep-changing-sectors-or-can-i-load-multiple) that you can safely load multiple sectors but for portability to buggy BIOSes you should avoid loading so many that you cross a cylinder boundary.  If that's the case use multiple calls.

---

It would be simpler to just make a combined kernel with a 16-bit entry point and load the whole thing from your bootloader with one 4-sector load.

You can use `BITS 16` and `BITS 32` within one NASM source file to assemble for 16-bit vs. 32-bit mode.  You can even use a label for the far-jmp to 32-bit code instead of to a hard-coded address where you load the code.

See also:

- [Boot loader doesn't jump to kernel code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701854/boot-loader-doesnt-jump-to-kernel-code/32705076#32705076)
- [How to make the kernel for my bootloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603842/how-to-make-the-kernel-for-my-bootloader)
- [How to load second stage boot loader from first stage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065370/how-to-load-second-stage-boot-loader-from-first-stage) (a two-stage bootloader setup is something like what you're asking about.)

Comment: i see, i will join the 2 kernels( makes sense now), thanks